# bootstrap primary color override doesn't work after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to override bootstrap 5's primary color using scss. This works fine until after I click a button that opens an external link.

Here is my scss file:

```
$primary: #ae217aff;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Here is my stylesheet import in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./html/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./html/animations.css" />
    <title>title</title>
    <script defer src="../render.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input
          type="url"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder=""
          required
        />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary"
            type="button"
            id="testBtn"
          >
            Get Spreadsheet Template
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </form>

    <script src="../render.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the javascript to open the link:

```
templateBtn = document.getElementById("testBtn");
templateBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  window.open(
    "",
    "_blank"
  );
```

My index.css file is the result of running the command "sass index.scss index.css" (aka compiling to a css file). Here is a before/after photo of the button click:

[image: Button before clicking][image: Button after clicking]

Comment: You should have only one (modified and) compiled version of bootstrap.css in your page.

Comment: @ITgoldman do you mean I should get rid of the stylesheet that imports bootstrap in index.html? would that still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the cdn version, and just use one scss-compiled version of bootstrap. Take advantage by changing variables of bootstrap AND using their variables in your classes.

From their [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#file-structure), I also use this approach:

```
// my-bootstrap-and-styles.scss

// your overrides
$primary : #FEBC35;

// include bootstrap.scss
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";   

// Then add your additional custom code here
.my-primary-div {
  background: $primary;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```