# change background color of a button in bootstrap 5 navbars

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I wanted to change a button background color in a bootstrap navbar but it was not change completely.
What should I have to do?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand bg-success" href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>
            ...
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6F1t.jpg).

Comment: What do you mean with 'was not change completely'? Have you try to inspect the element? please provide your css in [mcve]

Comment: See my recent answer about compiling and integrating with bootstrap sass https://stackoverflow.com/a/73114678/3807365

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the green background color from your logo you need to remove

```
bg-success
```

class form this code

```
<a class="navbar-brand bg-success" href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>
```

bootstrap provides many classes for buttons you can use any of them according to your project branding, types are

```
btn-primary
btn-secondary
btn-success
btn-danger
btn-warning
btn-info
btn-light
btn-dark
btn-link
```

Comment: I removed "bg-success" class and added "btn btn-success" class to the "a" tag, but again it has a default margin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your color background more predominant then make use of the attributes mentioned below in this tag:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand bg-success" href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>
```

```html
.bg-primary: This sets the color to the primary color.
.bg-secondary: This sets the color to the secondary color.
.bg-success: This sets the color to the success color.
.bg-danger: This sets the color to the danger color.
.bg-warning: This sets the color to the warning color.
.bg-info: This sets the color to the info color.
.bg-light: This sets the color to the light color.
.bg-dark: This sets the color to the dark color.
.bg-white: This sets the color to the white color.
.bg-transparent: This sets the navbar to be transparent.
```