# Bootstrap 5.1+ How to change colors (text, background, border) of alerts of a specific color (like alert-warning) inside custom _variables.scss

Tags: css, colors, alert, bootstrap-5

I am using a custom `_variables.scss` file, that is imported like that:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
@import 'variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "custom";
```

I tried to change the alert color like that, but this does nothing:

```
$alert-color: $orange;
$alert-bg: $orange;
$alert-border-color: $orange;
```

I know using css-variables is another way to do it. but i would like to have one central place to manage custom changes as far as possible.

My current Bootstrap version is 5.1. The solution should also work in 5.2, since i will update soon.

Comment: this is how i do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73114678/3807365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer, none of the following vars exist in Bootstrap: `$alert-color`, `$alert-bg` nor `$alert-border-color`.

The value you try to modify are defined like this in Bootstrap source code:

```scss
.alert {
  --#{$prefix}alert-bg: transparent;
  --#{$prefix}alert-color: inherit;
  --#{$prefix}alert-border-color: transparent;

  color: var(--#{$prefix}alert-color);
  background-color: var(--#{$prefix}alert-bg);
  border: var(--#{$prefix}alert-border);
}
```

So as you said you might want to use CSS vars instead (the following example modify the color or all alerts as orange):

```scss
.alert {
  --#{$prefix}alert-color: #{$orange}; // or --bs-alert-color: #{$orange};
}
```

---

There's another way to do this kind of things but it will only add a new theme color for each component and I'm not sure that's what you want:

```scss
$custom-colors: (
  "custom-color": #f61
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
```

So you'll be able to use:

```html
<div class="alert alert-custom-color" role="alert">
  A simple custom color alert—check it out!
</div>
```

But also

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-color">Primary</button>
```

---

Third possibility:

```scss
.alert-custom-color { // Creating your own class
// .alert would modify all the alerts
// .alert-warning would modify the rendering only for this one
  @include alert-variant(green, violet, yellow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer Julien. This helps a lot to understand better, what possibilities exist in Bootstrap currently. The Bootstrap documentation is missing important details like that.

Comment: I just search in `./node_modules/bootstrap` for "alert", i can't find the bootstrap 5.2 sourcecode you mention at the top of your answer?

Comment: I am now overwriting the standard "warning" color palette like that:
`$custom-colors: (
  "warning": #f61
);`

Comment: The source code for alerts can be found in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_alert.scss or in `./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_alerts.scss` in your local environment